# import image to imageview via button in tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uiimagepickercontroller

i want to import a photo via a button in a tableviw cell. so the button in the specific table view cell imports the image to the image view in that specfic cell. So one button imports a image to the one imageview in that specific cell. I tried to put the photo import code in the tableview cell class. The code is not compiling.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
    var numberOfRows = 3
  
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { numberOfRows }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 118
    }
 
    var tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setTableVIew()
     
    }
    
    func setTableVIew(){

        
        let VCframe = self.view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
        let widthx = VCframe.width
        
        
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthx, height: height)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


}
class customtv: UITableViewCell , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
      var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

           // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
           guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
               fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
           }

           // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.

           imageDisplayer.image = selectedImage

           // Dismiss the picker.
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }



       @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
           if let error = error {
               // we got back an error!
               let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
               ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
               present(ac, animated: true)
           } else {
               let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
               ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
               present(ac, animated: true)
           }
       }
    
   lazy var backView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width, height: 110))
    view.backgroundColor = .green
    print(self.frame.width)
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var press : UIButton = {
     let press = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 3, width: 65 , height: 50))
     press.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        press.setTitle("import", for: .normal)
        press.addTarget(self, action: #selector(importPhoto), for: .touchDown)
         return press
     }()
    
    lazy var imageDisplayer : UIImageView = {
     let press = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 3, width: 80 , height: 90))
     press.backgroundColor = .systemPink
         return press
     }()
    
    @objc func importPhoto(){
                    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
                    imagePicker.delegate = self
                    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
       backView.clipsToBounds = true

    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
        backView.addSubview(press)
        backView.addSubview(imageDisplayer)
    }
   
    

}
```

Comment: what is `customtv` reuse identifier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to present the `UIImagePickerController` in the `ViewController` instead of `customtv`.

In `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var numberOfRows = 3

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { numberOfRows }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 118 }

    var tableView = UITableView()
    var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setTableVIew()
    }

    func setTableVIew(){
        let VCframe = view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
        let widthx = VCframe.width

        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthx, height: height)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .blue

        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.press.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.press.addTarget(self, action: #selector(importPhoto), for: .touchDown)
        return cell
    }

    @objc func importPhoto(_ button: UIButton) {
        selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: 0)
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) as? customtv else { return }
        cell.imageDisplayer.image = selectedImage
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

In `customtv`:

```
class customtv: UITableViewCell {

    lazy var backView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width, height: 110))
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        print(self.frame.width)
        return view
    }()

    lazy var press : UIButton = {
        let press = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 3, width: 65 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        press.setTitle("import", for: .normal)
        return press
    }()

    lazy var imageDisplayer : UIImageView = {
        let press = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 3, width: 80 , height: 90))
        press.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        return press
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        backView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
        backView.addSubview(press)
        backView.addSubview(imageDisplayer)
    }
}
```